# No se reconoce columnas en consulta MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tengo esta consulta MYSQL:

```
SELECT nombre,
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (id_visitante = id_equipo AND visitante > local) 
OR (id_local = id_equipo AND local > visitante) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM resultado_jornada) AS JG,
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (id_visitante = id_equipo AND visitante < local) 
OR (id_local = id_equipo AND local < visitante) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM resultado_jornada) AS JP,
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (id_visitante = id_equipo AND visitante = local) 
OR (id_local = id_equipo AND local = visitante) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM resultado_jornada) AS E,
(JG / (JG + JP)) AS PTJE
FROM equipo
```

Lo que deseo es es generar una salida como esta

```
Equipo     JG JP E PTJE
Monterrey  7  3  0 .700
Laguna     5  5  0 .500
Saltillo   5  5  0 .500
Tijuana    7  3  0 .500
Olmecas    2  8  0 .200
Pericos    4  6  0 .400
```

El problema es que me lanza el error: *La columna 'JG' en field list es desconocida*

Como puedo solucionar ese problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con subquery:

```sql
SELECT X.nombre as 'Equipo',
       X.jg as 'JG',
       X.jp as 'JP',
       X.e as 'E',
       ( X.jg / ( X.jg + X.jp ) ) AS PTJE
FROM   (SELECT nombre,
               (SELECT Sum(CASE
                             WHEN ( id_visitante = id_equipo
                                    AND visitante > local )
                                   OR ( id_local = id_equipo
                                        AND local > visitante ) THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                           end)
                FROM   resultado_jornada) AS JG,
               (SELECT Sum(CASE
                             WHEN ( id_visitante = id_equipo
                                    AND visitante < local )
                                   OR ( id_local = id_equipo
                                        AND local < visitante ) THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                           end)
                FROM   resultado_jornada) AS JP,
               (SELECT Sum(CASE
                             WHEN ( id_visitante = id_equipo
                                    AND visitante = local )
                                   OR ( id_local = id_equipo
                                        AND local = visitante ) THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                           end)
                FROM   resultado_jornada) AS E,
               from                       equipo) AS X
```

Comment: Gracias si funciona